# PushPine ObjectID is Not Same as Selected ObjectID in ForgeViewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge, autodesk-bim360, pushpin

When Pushpine created in forgeViewer I want objectID of Particular PushPin seleted Solid Object?

But When go throught with  **issue.objectId** i am not as same as value when i selected same object with mouse click..

```
peter or any autodesk developer help me out....

var issue = PushPinExtensionHandle.getItemById('0');
// This is how the API expects to receive the data:
var data = {
  type: issue.type,
  attributes: {
    title: userForm.title, // In our example, this is the ``title`` the user sets in the form data (see step 3).
    // The extension retrieved the ``type`` and ``status`` properties in step 3, concatenated them, added a dash, and
    // assigned the new string to the ``status`` property of the newly created pushpin object. For example, ``issues-
    // open``.
    // You now need to extract the ``status`` (``open``) from the pushpin object.
    status: issue.status.split('-')[1] || issue.status,
    // The ``target_urn`` is the ID of the document (``item``) associated with an issue; see step 1.
    target_urn: 
    starting_version: <YOUR_VERSION_ID>, // See step 1 for the version ID.
    // The issue type ID and issue subtype ID. See GET ng-issue-types for more details.
    ng_issue_type_id: <ISSUE_TYPE_ID>
    ng_issue_subtype_id: <ISSUE_SUBTYPE_ID>
    // ``sheet_metadata`` is the sheet in the document associated with the pushpin.
    sheet_metadata: { // `viewerApp.selectedItem` references the current sheet
      is3D: viewerApp.selectedItem.is3D(),
      sheetGuid: viewerApp.selectedItem.guid(),
      sheetName: viewerApp.selectedItem.name()
    },
    pushpin_attributes: { // Data about the pushpin
      type: 'TwoDVectorPushpin', // This is the only type currently available
      object_id: issue.objectId, // (Only for 3D models) The object the pushpin is
      location: issue.position, // The x, y, z coordinates of the pushpin
      viewer_state: issue.viewerState // The current viewer state. For example, angle, camera, zoom
    },
  }
};
// See step 6 for de
```

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Looking at the JSON structure you posted, I can see the object ID stored under `data.attributes.pushpin_attributes.object_id`. Or is it missing? And are you working with 2D drawings or 3D models?

Comment: @PetrBroz I am Using the 3D model ,,,When I am Using SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT   getting object dbid is   var objSelected = viewer.getSelection()[0]; but When I selected a same object  using PUSH pins  I am not getting the same Object dbid as same as Getselection dbid...

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information, but it's possible that the pushpin actually points to a _child_ or to an _ancestor_ of the object you're expecting in the hierarchy tree.

Comment: @PetrBroz Hi,Concept is simple When I selected the object  using Pushpin ...i need selected object Properties ...How to fetch the selected OBject Properties?

Comment: In that case I would ask: who created the pushpin, and do you know that the pushpin is actually attached to the object you want? If it is, then the object ID in `data.attributes.pushpin_attributes.object_id` should be the one you're looking for.

Comment: Btw. it sounds like it would make more sense to discuss your specific issue on a zoom call. Feel free to book a 30min chat with me or one of my colleagues via https://calendly.com/autodeskforge.